# What is this resilient plant that prefers shade and little water?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I've inherited this plant that requires minimal care: just some watering every two weeks, and not much light. However, I forgot to water it for ~3 weeks, and it wilted. Took it on the balcony, where it sprung back to life, but then forgot it there for a whole day and now it looks like this :(

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry to say that this appears to be an ex plant - its impossible to tell what it was other than vague guesses. Remove it from sunlight back to indoors, out of sun but with good daylight,  cut the dead off, water a bit and see what happens. That might be signs of resurrection, or it might be a contribution to the compost heap, but if you haven't the time or energy to care for it anyway, probably best to compost or bin it now. Should you decide you want to learn to care for it, and it shows signs of rising from the dead, then repost a photo once its showing signs of life for further advice.

Comment: For a good ID it could be useful to see the stem also.

Comment: Possibly Spathiphyllum - but that's  a wild guess going by the "forensic evidence". Apart from that, please heed @Bamboo's advice.

Comment: Yup, sad to say this guy is toast!   Peace Lily...Spathiphyllum that Stephie said...get a new one and then tell your friend who gave this plant to you that heck, you just have a green thumb!